# Odd text characters appearing next to menus, in links and replaced social media links on Theme256K

Tags: admin, magento-1, template, css

We have suddenly found text characters next to the menu items on our site.  Links for catalogue products also have a `|` symbol which is not normally there, and the small thumbnails for the social media links have been replaced by text. I have scoured the system settings to see why this has happened and can find nothing that gives and clues. The domain is http://www.havdirect.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Your site url is already in secure mode and below css has not identify as Secure.

```
http://havdirect.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/theme257k/css/havdirect-webfont.css
```

Can you please make them secure like `https://havdirect.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/theme257k/css/havdirect-webfont.css`

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply.  I can see what you mean. Should that path not have that structure anyhow as it is within the public_html on a secure site?  Where do I change the path then?

Comment: @Paul , May be this css file include in head.phtml in below dierctory , 
public_html/app/design/frontend/default/theme257k/template/page/html/head.phtml